# GET https://username.github.io/runtime net::ERR_ABORTED 404 build in github

Tags: github, build, github-pages, angular12

The dist folder works normal on publishing server, but got error while i am publishing in github using gitpage, i had attached the link to my repo for code information.

[image]

Comment: Your code needs to be in your question. Otherwise it will not be helpful anymore once you change your repo.

Comment: @JamesZ the error was not in a code but some problem in git page, it works normal in different server but not works if i will host on gitpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is solved using below steps...
1.) change `<base href="https://username.github.io/reponame/"> to <base href="/https://username.github.io/reponame/">` by putting / at the starting it works.